# Automating hotplug events for USB in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, hotplugging

I am working on mini router project and would like to automate USB Hotplug events when device is plugged in routed.

Kernel version used is 2.6.30 and its configured with CONFIG_HOTPLUG.

I googled and also scripted hotplug scripts but not getting events on holplug. Can anybody glimpse in to solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your hotplug script path in `/proc/sys/kernel/hotplug` file:

```
echo /path/to/hotplug/script > /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug
```

The default path is `/sbin/hotplug`.

If you are using bash script for debbuging hotplug like this

```
#!/bin/bash
env >> /your/log/file
```

make sure you have specified an absolute path of `/your/log/file` and the script is executable (just run it by hand and see if it works).

Moreover, if udev is installed on your device, try to capture uevents with udev and see if they are generated by kernel:

```
udevadm monitor
```